# mod_rewrite: how to prioritize files over folders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/name1
http://www.example.com/name1/
http://www.example.com/name1/test1
```

and I have a file/folder structure that looks like this

```
src
|
----name1.html
|
----name1
    |
    ----test2.html
```

1) If a user visits e.g. `http://www.example.com/name1` or `http://www.example.com/name1/` (w/ trailing slash) I want to serve the html-file.

2) If a user visits e.g. `http://www.example.com/name1/test1` I want to serve the html-file inside the folder `test1`.

The different solutions I could find on SO always use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to make sure it isn't a directory - but I also want to rewrite the URL if it is an existing dir, as long as there is a html-file with the same name.

Happy about any input you can provide.

cheers

*** edit ***

what I have so far looks something like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1

RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Comment: I have the feeling I am missing something. What prevents you from simply rewriting the url to the url with .html behind it if that is not already the case?

Comment: @Sumurai8 that's what I tried, but I have to remove the trailing slash at the beginning (if present) and then add the .html and check if it's a file that can be served. I'll add an example of what I have so far...

Comment: just move name1.html to name1/index.html -> problem solved

Comment: Keep in mind that you can check if something *is* a file by doing this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is that `mod_dir` undoes whatever you tried to do. If you have a file `test.php` and a directory `test/` with in it `index.php`, `mod_rewrite` will rewrite the request, and then `mod_dir` will completely disregard that and inject `test/index.php` as the url and do the .htaccess file all over again. To get this working, you have to disable `DirectoryIndex`. To prevent Apache from automatically adding a slash after the url if there is a directory with the same name, `DirectorySlash` must be turned off as well.

After that, it is pretty straight-forward. You match anything without a dot (just so we don't do unnecessary file-checks) and leave a trailing slash, if one exists, outside the capture group. You then use this capture group (`%1`) to create a filename to see if it exists. If it does, the request is rewritten.

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([^.]*?)/?$
RewriteCond %1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: (If you are curious, this is the complete log when you don't turn off DirectoryIndex and DirectorySlash: http://pastebin.com/5RQrtmCp; you will notice that halfway it magically changes to a different url.

Comment: looks like this is working - haven't used the `DirectorySlash` and `DirectoryIndex` directives before! thank you very much.